# How to upload video to facebook straight from the users machine

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I want to upload a video to facebook group. Have a site built in asp.net mvc5.
Found tons of examples in google but not 1 uploading straight from the users machine to facebook. Would love a simple example